# (.NET MAUI / MVVM Toolkit) IsVisible doesn't show until back button is pressed or keyboard is shown

Tags: c#, mvvm, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

I've been facing issues using .NET MAUI with the MVVM Community Toolkit. The UI doesn't quite update whenever I try to call a command that makes a layout become visible ie. a popup.

I tried to replicate this issue using a smaller program. The button makes the IsLoading property true for 3 seconds. The IsLoading is bound to a popup's IsVisible property, so the popup should appear for 3 seconds.

When I press the button, no popup appears. Setting a breakpoint confirms that IsLoading is set to true. However, if I interact with the screen somehow during that 3-second time frame, such as pressing the back button or selecting an entry and pulling out the keyboard, the popup suddenly appears. From this point onward, all subsequent button clicks work as intended.

Here are the relevant files I used:

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="NoUpdate.MainPage">
    
        <Grid>
            
            <VerticalStackLayout 
                Spacing="25" 
                Padding="30,0" 
                VerticalOptions="Center">
    
                <Button Text="Loading Button"
                        Command="{Binding ShowPopupCommand}"/>
    
                <Entry Placeholder="Entry"/>
    
            </VerticalStackLayout>
    
            <VerticalStackLayout
                HeightRequest="200"
                WidthRequest="200"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                BackgroundColor="Beige"
                IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}">
    
                <Label Text="Loading..."/>
    
            </VerticalStackLayout>
            
        </Grid>
     
    </ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    namespace NoUpdate;
    
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewmodel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = viewmodel;
        }
    }
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs:**

```
    namespace NoUpdate;
    using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
    using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
    
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isLoading = false;
    
        [RelayCommand]
        async Task ShowPopup()
        {
            IsLoading = true;
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

Here are some screenshots:
[Launch Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6bc8.jpg)

[Button clicked, no popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgiR4.jpg)

[While button is down, tapped on an entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xVtd.jpg)

Any thoughts? Sorry, I'm an still an intern and this is my first ever experience with .NET and MVVM so I'm not really sure what to look for about this problem. Any advice is appreciated. Please do let me now if I'm missing anything. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `ShowPopupCommand`  for the button like below:

```
        [ICommand]
        async Task ShowPopup()
        {
            IsLoading = true;
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            IsLoading = false;
        }
```